# Problem running ./gradlew signingReport on vs code

Tags: java, flutter, visual-studio-code, gradle

I'm working on a flutter project in vs code, and I'm trying to run `./gradlew signingReport` to get the SHA1 certificate but when I try to run that I get the following error message:

> Could not compile build file 'C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-4.3.1\android\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
> General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 63

I've looked around and there seems to be some kind of problem with the way the java versions are set up, but I don't know what or where to change.

If you need more information from me to help me solve this please tell me what can I provide, this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

> Unsupported class file major version 63

As far as I know, class file major version 63 needs [java19](https://www.oracle.com/news/announcement/oracle-releases-java-19-2022-09-20/).

I think you have to update it.

Comment: With java19 the error kept showing up.
I had to change to java17 and the problem disappeared, but this feels hacky, like the problem is somewhere else and I just patched it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on java-19 do this to solve this error:-

[Unsupported class file major version 63](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MujYC.jpg)

just go at your project folder and then open android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper-properties

then change this :-

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

To This :-

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

and then your issue get solved